# Trying to retrieve a file from another computer on same network

Tags: file, asp.net-core, lan

I am trying to copy an image file from a computer on the same network as mine, but running into an exception.

I am running as aspnet core app on a Raspberry Pi.  The computer with the image is an android device on the same network.
The address of the image to be copied is:  ftp://172.18.10.190:8010/records/2019-07-26/157395.jpg
I can put that link into a browser and retrieve the image, but I would like to save it to the Pi.

I have tried using File.Copy:

```cs
System.IO.File.Copy("ftp://172.18.10.190:8010/records/2019-07-26/157395.jpg", directory + "/" + "157395.jpg");
```

I am getting a directory not found error:
NotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'home/pi/pcmonitor/ftp:/172.18.10.190:8010/records/2019-07-26/157395.jpg'

It looks like the 'home/pi/pcmonitor/'is being pre-pended along with one of the forward slashes after ftp being deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not copy or download ftp file through `File.Copy`.

You need to send request and save the response like

```
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpPath);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xx", "xx");

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
using (var fileStream = File.Create(localPath))
{
    responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}

Console.WriteLine($"Download Complete, status {response.StatusDescription}");

response.Close();
```